# Java Cloudinary using maven

Tags: java, maven, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload images to cloudinary using Java:

The maven is the one that is on the cloudinary documentation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudinary</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.14</version>
  </dependency>
```

The Java code to upload is:
    Map uploadResult = cloudinary.uploader().upload(fileUpload, Cloudinary.emptyMap());

But this gives me the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [standard] in context with path [/standard] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.cloudinary.Util.buildUploadParams(Util.java:41)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you don't have a dependency to `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join`?

Comment: I have this dependency: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: You might be having an older version of `commons-lang` also.

Comment: I also updated (and also removed) the commons-lang to the last one: <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
   <version>2.6</version>
  </dependency> and still have the same error

Comment: I found the problem. Instead of using Cloudinary.emptyMap() I start using ObjectUtils.emptyMap() in the upload method and everything worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `Cloudinary.emptyMap()` is deprecated, and `ObjectUtils.emptyMap()` should be used instead.
Also, the dependencies were changed a little bit with the new Java library version. If you're building a JAVA app, you can use something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudinary-http42</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version> 
</dependency>
```

For android, use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudinary-android</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```